# Detect links in message in specific category

Tags: node.js, discord.js

I would like to allow the link to be sent only to channels in certain categories and not to channels in other categories, but it doesn't work.

Here is what I have tried:

```js
if (message.content.includes('discord.gg/'||'discordapp.com/invite/'||'https://'||'http://'))
{
    if (message.author.guild.channels.get(c => c.name == "Link" && c.type == "category"))
        return;
}
else
    message.delete().then(message.reply('U Cant Send Link In Here. Go To Link category'))
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You try get `message.author.guild.` message author its a [`user`](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/User) so he dont have any guild property. When you try find `message.guild.channels` or `message.member.guild.channels` its always will return true, if guild has this channnel. It does not depend on the channel for sending the message.  The right way is check channel parrent and if parrent name !== somethink, then delete msg.

And still better replace `message.channel.parent.name === 'Link'` to `message.channel.parent.id === 'CATEGORY ID'`

```
if (message.content.includes('discord.gg/'||'discordapp.com/invite/'||'https://'||'http://')) {
    if(message.channel.parent.name === 'Link') return
     message.delete().then(msg => message.reply('U Cant Send Link In Here. Go To Link category')) 
}
```

Answer (score 0):

`message.author.guild.channels.get(c => c.name == "Link" && c.type == "category")`wont work, since it only takes a single key. See here: [Map#get](https://developer.mozilla.org/de/docs/Web/JavaScript/Reference/Global_Objects/Map/get)

What you would need to do it to use the find function. Since Discord.js uses Collections (basically Map's with additional functions) you have access to additional utility functions. See here: [Discord.js#Collections](https://discord.js.org/#/docs/main/stable/class/Collection). And via find() you can use functions just fine.

```js
message.author.guild.channel.find(c => c.name == "Link" && c.type == "category")
```

Comment: Hello ^^ Thanks for your answer! I still has a little error in it...Error is ```if (message.author.guild.channels.find(c => c.name == "Link" && c.type == "category")) ^ TypeError: Cannot read property 'channels' of undefined –```

Comment: You could try `if (message.guild.channels.find(c => c.name == "Link" && c.type == "category"))`